# Random "Sorry, my bot code is having a issue" message appearing during chat

Tags: azure, error-handling, bots, botframework

Bit of a weird one but I am getting this error almost randomly when going through a dialog with my bot. It is very inconsistent and appears at any point during the conversation. The dialog itself works as intended so it leads me to suspect that there might be something that triggers the error from the controller. (posted below)

Has anyone encountered this before? Could it be because of how it is hosted? What would you suggest would be the best approach to solve this as the error handling does not provide any information I can find apart from this vague error message.

Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks!

Controller:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;

namespace ExampleBot
{
    [BotAuthentication]
    public class MessagesController : ApiController
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// POST: api/Messages
        /// Receive a message from a user and reply to it
        /// </summary>
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
        {
            if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
            {

                await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.RootDialog());
            }
            else
            {
                HandleSystemMessage(activity);
            }
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            return response;
        }

        private Activity HandleSystemMessage(Activity message)
        {
            if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData)
            {
                // Implement user deletion here
                // If we handle user deletion, return a real message
            }
            else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
            {
                // Handle conversation state changes, like members being added and removed
                // Use Activity.MembersAdded and Activity.MembersRemoved and Activity.Action for info
                // Not available in all channels
            }
            else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate)
            {
                // Handle add/remove from contact lists
                // Activity.From + Activity.Action represent what happened
            }
            else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Typing)
            {
                // Handle knowing tha the user is typing
            }
            else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Ping)
            {
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That error is thrown by Microsofts [BotBuilder Framework](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Sorry%2C+my+bot+code+is+having+a+issue&type=)

Answer (score 1):

`Sorry, my bot code is having a issue` is the generic message displayed by the bot framework when an error occured on server side. If you are using the webchat, you can see on your navigator tools http calls replying with response code 500.

In your case, there is nothing special in the Controller you provided that may throw an error, there must be something else. You can investigate by checking the logs and/or adding ApplicationInsights to your project to get more details about the encountered exception.

Comment: Going through the logs the error message is: 
"There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code InternalServerError" and "There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code GatewayTimeout" but the message often still comes through just accompanied by the posted message. The bot is hosted on Azure, but from what I can see from the forums:"https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2161" this seems to be happening to more than just me and for a while. Any ideas?

Comment: You have 2 separate errors here. You may investigate the one about InternalServerError, by adding ApplicationInsights and looking at the exceptions that are catched

Answer (score 1):

You might want to override the default behavior for generic error, so that when it occurs you can change the default error message and break while debugging and look at the exception.

I often get botframwork errors and this helps me investigate the issues.

Add a new component:

```cs
public class PostUnhandledExceptionToUser : IPostToBot
{
    private readonly ResourceManager resources;
    private readonly IPostToBot inner;
    private readonly IBotToUser botToUser;
    private readonly TraceListener trace;

    public PostUnhandledExceptionToUser(IPostToBot inner, IBotToUser botToUser, ResourceManager resources, TraceListener trace)
    {
        SetField.NotNull(out this.inner, nameof(inner), inner);
        SetField.NotNull(out this.botToUser, nameof(botToUser), botToUser);
        SetField.NotNull(out this.resources, nameof(resources), resources);
        SetField.NotNull(out this.trace, nameof(trace), trace);
    }

    async Task IPostToBot.PostAsync(IActivity activity, CancellationToken token)
    {
        try
        {
            await this.inner.PostAsync(activity, token);
        }
        catch(HttpException hex)
        {
            try
            {
                //Post my custom error message
                await this.botToUser.PostAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultErrorMessage"]);
            }
            catch (Exception inner)
            {
                this.trace.WriteLine(inner);
            }

            throw hex;
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Debugger.IsAttached)
                {
                    var message = this.botToUser.MakeMessage();
                    message.Text = $"Exception: { error.Message}";
                    message.Attachments = new[]
                    {
                        new Attachment(contentType: MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain, content: error.StackTrace)
                    };

                    await this.botToUser.PostAsync(message);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception inner)
            {
                this.trace.WriteLine(inner);
            }

            throw;
        }
    }

}
```

Register the component in autofac and add it to the end of the chain:

```
protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    builder.RegisterType<PostUnhandledExceptionToUser>().Keyed<IPostToBot>(typeof(PostUnhandledExceptionToUser)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();


    RegisterAdapterChain<IPostToBot>(builder,
            typeof(EventLoopDialogTask),
            typeof(SetAmbientThreadCulture),
            typeof(PersistentDialogTask),
            typeof(ExceptionTranslationDialogTask),
            typeof(SerializeByConversation),
            typeof(PostUnhandledExceptionToUser),
            typeof(LogPostToBot)
        )
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
}
```